# Remove part of string from each line of a textfile

Tags: c#, .net, linq, text-files

I am working on a program where I am copying links from gmail inbox and save it in a text file, the link that is copied also have some unwanted characters, and I want to get rid of those unwanted characters. please help.

here is my code.

Here is the function of copying links:

```
public void grabAuthentication()
{
    HtmlElementCollection links = webBrowser4.Document.Links;

    using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter("activation.txt", true))
    {
        foreach (HtmlElement link in links)
        {
            if (link.OuterHtml.Contains("https://example.com"))
            {
                tw.WriteLine(link.InnerHtml);

            }
        }

    }

}
```

Firing the function on a button click :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   grabAuthentication();
}
```

Example of links collected in textfile :

```
https://example.com/<WBR>verify/<WBR>y8sURA0egNgcaUyMlOapqQ8ehleNDv<WBR>L6Pu48Pkg0
https://example.com/<WBR>verify/<WBR>PtjKgpMuqeAchnvZus7nDCnJ6oKfdr<WBR>oFX1k8dIBSs
https://example.com/<WBR>verify/<WBR>xtojDKjbNzXWYKTDlTqmFmRZGRcXax<WBR>TvTEADaGQ
```

Now I want to remove  from each line of textfile which occurs 3 times in each line.

Comment: Have tried html.decode?

Comment: No, I didnt yet. let me test

Comment: What you want to remove ??

Comment: want to remove <WVR> from each line of collected link @Muhammad Umar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String.Replace` may help you.

```
 if (link.OuterHtml.Contains("https://example.com"))
 {
      tw.WriteLine(link.InnerHtml.Replace("<WBR>", null));
 }
```